# how to prove that $ \lim x_n^{y_n}=\lim x_n^{\lim y_n}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences of real numbers, such that:

$\lim x_n = a > 0$ and $\lim y_n = b \in \mathbb R$

I need to prove that:

$$\lim \left( x_n ^{y_n} \right) = a^b$$

I tried using Cauchy's criterion:

$|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|y_n-b|<\epsilon$, and then we need to prove that $\left| x_n ^{y_n} -a^b\right|<\epsilon$, but I didn't find a way of proving it.

Comment: Note that $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$ (or how else do you define arbitrary powers?

Comment: Note $x_n^{y_n}=\exp(y_n\ln x_n)$. Since $\exp$ is continuous, it suffices to show $y_n\ln x_n\to b\ln a$. This should follow from $\ln x_n\to \ln a$ (as $\ln$ is continuous) and the fact that products of convergent sequences are convergent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to know how to prove that $x_n y_n \to xy$ if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

Next, $\exp$ and $\ln$ are continuous functions, so we have:

$$\lim x_n ^{y_n} = \lim e^{y_n \ln(x_n)} = e^{\lim y_n \ln(x_n)} = e^{b \ln(\lim x_n)} = e^{b\ln(a)} = a^b $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Begin trying to prove that $\lim_n\ln x_n=\ln a$. Then try to prove that $\lim_n (y_n \ln x_n)=b \ln a$. Finally prove that $\ln(\lim_n x_n)=\lim_n \ln x_n$.